# Converting binary to Binary String: leading zero

Tags: java

I keep getting 0 in front of the resulting binary.

```
  public static String convertToBinaryString(int testSubject){


    if(testSubject == 0){
      return binaryString = "0"; 
    }

    else{
      return convertToBinary(testSubject / 2) + "" + testSubject % 2;
    }

  }
```

How do I get rid of the leading zero?

Comment: Don't recurse into the last case.

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of unused variables?

Comment: Why `return binaryString = "0"; ` instead of just `return "0"`?

Comment: As usual in these questions, for some reason, there is no decimal to binary conversion here. The `int` variable is already binary. What you are doing is converting binary to printable binary.

Answer (score 5):

One way to fix this is to stop recursing as soon as `testSubject < 2`:

```
if (testSubject < 2) {
    return "" + testSubject % 2;
} else {
    return convertToBinary(testSubject / 2) + "" + testSubject % 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use build in function

```
   int x = 50;
    String s = Integer.toBinaryString(x);
    return s;
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-integer-tobinarystring-method/

Answer (score 0):

There are other simpler ways of doing it.
Your program has recursion overhead, which can be prevented using simple loop.

```
public static String convertToBinary(int testSubject) {
    // Method 1
    //   return Integer.toBinaryString(testSubject);

    // Method 2
    String str = "";
    while(testSubject!=0) {
      str = testSubject%2 + str;
      testSubject/=2;
    }
    return str;
  }
```